# Write Filestream into StreamWriter in c#

Tags: c#, xml, file, filestream, streamwriter

I would like to write a `FileStream` into a `StreamWriter` and I am not success because I am getting: `System.IO.FileStream` as result.

Here is mycode.

```
using (System.IO.FileStream c2pStreamFile = new System.IO.FileStream(FilePathName,  FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (StreamWriter logStream = new StreamWriter(TraceFilePathName, true))
    {

       logStream.WriteLine(c2pStreamFile);
       logStream.Flush();
       logStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) instead

```
using (FileStream c2pStreamFile =File.OpenRead(FilePathName))
{
    using (FileStream logStream = File.Open(TraceFilePathName,FileMode.Append))
    {
       c2pStreamFile.CopyTo(logStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont be fooled by naming `logStream` isn't a `Stream`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `FileStream` inherits from `stream`.Though `StreamWriter ` doesn't! edited the ans

Comment: Much better now, I suspect this will over write `logStream`

Comment: @Anirudh Why do I have to use `c2pStreamFile.CopyTo(logStream)` twice?

Comment: You are copying `FileStream` `to FileStream` where is the `StreamWriter` which OP asked for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to use a StreamReader to read the data in the FileStream. A StreamWriter is used to write output into a stream.

Check the example in this doc [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)

Comment: His question is clear, he want to write content of file to a StreamWriter, as he also show in his code.